# How to combine a set of Observables into one Observable?

Tags: rx-java

I have a `List` of data models, `User` in the example below, returned from a `webService` (Retrofit). I split the `List` into elements and emit them one by one so to `filter` them somehow. Then I need to combine all filtred `User`s and create a `List` of them. Please check out the code below so it is more clear.

```
webService.getUsers() // returns Observable<List<User>>
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(users -> Observable.from(users)) // split the collection of Users, so we can filter them next step 
        .filter(user -> user.getId() % 2 == 0) // get only Users with even id
        // How to transform from here to have a List<User> ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the RxJava [`toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toList()) operator after your `filter()` operator.